# How to add a X to clear input field

Tags: datatables

I'm using datatable.js on two pages.
On one there is an X to clear the input field, on the other there isn't

When I use the dom inspector in chrome, there is nothing in the dom where the X is.

I think I have set the same options on both pages; what am I missing?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can achieve by `jQuery` inside `DataTable` initiliazation in `initComplete` function to get `search input` and `wrap` div with help of `Bootstrap4 predefined classes` because of input `type="search"` cross icon only visible on Chromium browsers not on all browsers.

Answer (score 6):

It would be nice with an actual example. By the screenshot it seem to me you are using different stylings, and I guess bootstrap4 on the second page. Bootstrap intentionally remove the `×` by

```css3
[type="search"] { -webkit-appearance: none; }
```

If you are using DataTables bootstrap4 styling you can force the cancel button to reappear in the DT filter input box by

```css
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button !important;
  -moz-appearance: button !important; 
}
```

This is a WebKit/Blink issue. I think the edge equiv is called `::-ms-clear`, but have no windows to test it with.

---

Demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/au0j4h89/**

Comment: You are right about bootstrap4, but your css didn't help.

Comment: @LeifNeland, weird. Have updated the answer with a jsfiddle.  It works here (try comment out the CSS) but have only tested with Chrome.

Comment: @davidkonrad I tested with `Firefox` but no luck to see clear button. I think this is render on Chromium browsers only.

Comment: wonderful, you saved my daily +2 hours works, many thanks

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. For those indicating they don't see a clear button, you must have text in the search field before a clear button will display.

Answer (score 2):

Inside Datatable initialization to set **initComplete** function to get **input** type and wrap **div**+**button** with help of `Bootstrap4` predefined classes and also write some tricky css for `show` & `hide` cross button when input has some value then **show** cross if not then **hide**.
Also added **click functionality** on `cross` button for `redraw` datatable and set input null by `.search('')`.
Its working on all Browsers.
I hope below snippet will help you lot.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#example').DataTable({
    initComplete: function(settings) {
      //settings.nTable.id --> Get table ID
      $('#'+settings.nTable.id+'_filter input').wrap(`
       <div class="d-inline-flex position-relative"></div>
      `).after(`
       <button type="button" class="close position-absolute" aria-label="Close" style="right:5px">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
       </button>
      `).attr('required','required').attr('title','Search');

      // Click Event on Clear button
      $(document).on('click', '#'+settings.nTable.id+'_filter button', function(){
         $('#'+settings.nTable.id).DataTable({
           "retrieve": true,
          }).search('').draw(); // reDraw table
      });
     }
  });
});
```

```css
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input:not(:valid):not(:focus){
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff!important;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none!important;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter button{
  visibility: hidden;
  outline: none;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input:valid ~ button{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid my-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <table id="example" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th> date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
           <td>System Architect</td>
           <td>Edinburgh</td>
           <td>61</td>
           <td>2011/04/25</td>
           <td>$320,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
             <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
             <td>Edinburgh</td>
             <td>22</td>
             <td>2012/03/29</td>
             <td>$433,060</td>
           </tr>
          </tbody> 
        </table>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```